# Cumulative volume of multiple instruments/contracts

Tags: pine-script, volume

Is there a way to plot cumulative volume bars in pine script for different instruments/contracts.
For eg - the additive result of volume in multiple contracts-(current expiry + next expiry) of same instrument -(say S&P futures), bar by bar like normal volume ,plotted on the current expiry chart. Also by extension, can this be done for combination of instruments?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out these open source codes in TV , This will help you to plot cumulative volume bars in pine script for different instruments/contracts.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/GV4I6F7M-Cumulative-Volume/
https://in.tradingview.com/script/QSwFUbOw-NSE-CNX-FUTURES-Cumulative-Open-Interest-Volume/

Comment: Thanks!. The 2nd link was the thing I was searching for.

Comment: Glad ,It helped you out :-)